# how to get json data in javascript if json data have '/' in data key name

Tags: javascript, json

Certainly people having same problem and solution earlier than me on SO but unfortunately i didn't find so i have to create new question here.

I have JSON like

```
{
    "NewDataSet": [
        {
            "USD/INR": 
            {
                "DateTime": "2015-09-24 13:14:59.0",
                "percentChange": "0.25",
                "netChange": "0.16",
                "name": "USD/INR",
                "bidprice": "66.16"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to access data from USD/INR node in JavaScript. i am trying like: `NewDataSet.USD/INR.DateTime`   create JS error like `'Uncaught ReferenceError: INR is not defined'`

Comment: It's good you asked, instead of "figuring out" how to use eval() for this...

Comment: `NewDataSet['USD/INR'].DateTime`

Comment: @Jaromanda X NewDataSet['USD/INR'].DateTime returned undefined...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: @JaromandaX NewDataSet is an array so you missed [0] or a loop

Comment: I didn't realise the OP had no idea at all, I just read the attempt and fixed the obvious mistake

Comment: If you have a JSON string, which you imply, you need to parse it first: `var data = JSON.parse(jsonstring);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've used `JSON.parse(json)` to parse your JSON, you have to recognise that `NewDataSet` is an array, so you grab the first element using `[0]`:

```
var dateTime = obj.NewDataSet[0]['USD/INR'].DateTime;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rsmxevf7/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var g = x.NewDataSet[0] // as it an array, just pick the first object in it
g["USD/INR"] // output object content
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `DateTime` value like this:

```
    var a = {
    "NewDataSet": [
        {
            "USD/INR": 
            {
                "DateTime": "2015-09-24 13:14:59.0",
                "percentChange": "0.25",
                "netChange": "0.16",
                "name": "USD/INR",
                "bidprice": "66.16"
            }
        }
    ]
};

var dateTime = a.NewDataSet[0]['USD/INR']['DateTime']; // Result data
```